# How to normalize input for machine learning (neural networking) on video games

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Recently, I have been creating neural networks with the plan to train them to play games that I have made (where the neural networks have access to all of the game data).  I have a strong understanding of neural networks, genetic algorithms, and the NEAT implementation.  The issue that I have run into, however, is normalizing the input for what the player sees.  If we have an enemy object, a medkit object, and a weapon object, they need to be input and treated differently.  I saw a video from SethBling [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44), where he gives a brief explaination to how he set that neural network up.  He used only the values 1, 0, and -1.  However, for more complex games, that wouldn't work.  I've tried getting a small simulation to return true when the input is .25 < x < .75 and false otherwise, however it couldn't find a solution.  Therefore, it seems that I cannot just toss the IDs of the objects into the neural network.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was going to leave a comment, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points. So, I have a couple of suggestions that will hopefully give you some ideas. I am going to assume that you are using the NEAT algorithm as your game playing algorithm. Now, from what I gather your issue is that because you have a varying number of actual objects to interact with in your game it is practically impossible to give everything a label for every frame. Therefore, as you seem to have figured out you would need to provide a non-integer domain for the objects, whether that be normalizing the detected class id by the total number of classes, or some other method. I have 3 propositions for you in order to try to accomplish this (or avoid the problem):

1: Use some type of image manipulation (whether it be segmentation or thresholding), object detection along with image moments in order to create a database of objects that you are interested in, and then while the game is playing, you can re-create a simpler version of the actual game environment

2: Train a semantic segmentation neural network in order to perform something similar to 1

3: Train (or use a pre-trained) deep convolutional neural network to extract high-level features. Then use these features (and potentially some kind of location encoding method) as the input to your NEAT algorithm. Your NEAT algorithm would then select which combination of filters it would like to look at in order to make the decision.

I think I would personally try option number 3 as it requires the least amount of manual work in order to set up initially.

I hope this gives you a couple of ideas.

Comment: I already have the entire environment boiled down to a simpler version (as you mentioned in option 1), however, the main issue is taking the object IDs and turning them into meaningful input.  For example, the Enemy object has the ID of 1, the Coin object has an ID of 2, et cetera and it needs to be normalized into data for the neural network to read.  Mind you, ALL Coins have an ID of 2, even if there are twenty of them in the environment.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can just normalize your data to the range of your activation function. For example, if you have 10 different objects (ie. 10 different IDs), then you just take the ID for the object and divide it by 10. In your example, the enemy would have a normalized id of 0.1 and the coin would have a normalized id of 0.2. This allows you to encode the IDs into the range of the activation function which prevents the saturation of the network.

Answer (score 0):

When working with neural networks a good aproach is to think of them as humans. What would a human need to know?
What I always do is I give a network different sensors for different types of things. My sensors are almost always just rays of a certain length. 
In your situation I believe you have no better choice than using for example 3 sensors for coins, 3 sensors for medic cits etc. 
You also have to decide if you want to use boolean sensors (which would only tell the network if something triggered the sensor or not, no matter how close) or double sensors (which would return a value telling the network how close the event happened) or if you want to have both combined.